# Raspberry pi No module named 'cx_Oracle'

Tags: oracle11g, raspberry-pi, python-import

I want to use the raspberry pi to send values to the Oracle11g database, but when I run `import cx_Oracle` syntax for that process, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/20190222ex01.py", line 1, in <module>
    import cx_Oracle
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/thonny/backend.py", line 317, in _custom_import
    module = self._original_import(*args, **kw)
ImportError: No module named 'cx_Oracle'
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Update: Oracle has released Oracle Instant Client ARM64: https://www-sites.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/linux-arm-aarch64-downloads.html

Answer (score 0):

It means, that you have not installed module `cx_Oracle`.

First you must install Oracle driver with `PIP`:

```
python -m pip install cx_Oracle --upgrade
```

Hope it helped you.

Comment: I've tried your method. There are no errors in the terminal. However, I would like to code in the PUTTY window, but import cx_Oracle will get an error that there are no modules. By any chance, can you tell me how to solve it?

Comment: maybe you are using python3? try `pip3 install cx_Oracle`

Comment: Thank you. This problem has been solved.
But then there was this problem.
Run cx_Oracle.connect cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 32-bit Oracle Client library: "libclntsh.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory". See https://oracle.github.io/odpi/doc/installation.html#linux for help This is a problem. Can you help me?

Comment: Hi. As @Christopher Jones mentioned above, problem is, that there is no version of cx_Oracle for ARM architecture. Unfortunately it not gonna work. I cant help you.