# Tell me how to access OracleDB from Raspberry Pi through QUERY

Tags: python-3.x, oracle, raspberry-pi, cx-oracle, instantclient

The problem is the link between raspberry pie and Oracle database. We've tried a lot of things now, but the problem isn't solved. After downloading the oracleinstantclient-32bit Basic files and sqlplus files via the web from the raspberry pie, unpack the file collection and set the absolute path export `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `PATH` as well. But always:

```
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: DPI-1047: Canot location a 32-bit Oracle Client library: "libclntsh.so: cannot open shared object file or directory". See https://oracle.github.Issues such as io/odpi/doc/installation.html#linux for help.
```

I'd like to access Oracle DB from Python through QUERY statements from Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you've asked here a couple times ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54824962/raspberry-pi-no-module-named-cx-oracle/54858004#54858004) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55043656/tell-me-how-to-use-a-raspberry-pi-to-store-values-in-the-database-through-an-ora)), but maybe the answers were confusing? Let me be clear.

**[You cannot run Oracle Client on Raspberry Pi.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26167682/oracle-instant-client-for-arm-based-debian-device)***

Oracle does not support the ARM CPU architecture which the Raspberry Pi uses. You downloaded and unzipped the Oracle Instant Client, but it can't actually run. And without the Oracle Client libraries, cx_oracle will not work, and neither will generic Python ODBC connectors.

There are some alternatives to using Oracle Instant Client - the linked answer above lists some, and [the Python documentation lists others](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Oracle).

The easiest way is probably to use the Oracle JDBC library to connect - install JPype, [JayDeBeApi](https://pypi.org/project/JayDeBeApi/) and the Oracle JDBC library (ojdbc7.jar).

* Okay, you technically can run Oracle Client on Raspberry Pi, [people have done it by running a $30 x86 emulator](https://blog.dbi-services.com/running-the-oracle-client-on-a-raspberry-pi/). But that's probably more complicated than you want.