# Python thread was stop after jaydebeapi.connect

Tags: python, java, raspberry-pi, jvm, jaydebeapi

I'm using Python on Raspberry Pi. And I'm using JDBC to connect to the Oracle database. The problem is that sometimes the thread shuts down while I'm connecting to JDBC.

```
    conn = jaydebeapi.connect("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver", dsn, [user, password], jdbc_path)
    period = (time.time() - start_time)
    self.logger.debug("conn_period: " + str(period))
    print("conn_period: " + str(period))
```

After jaydebeapi.connect, I can't get debug log "conn_period" sometimes.

I think in jadebeapi it's stuck in an infinite loop. Because I didn't get any errors in the try exception syntax.
There is no other way than jaydebeapi so I want to know how to solve this problem.
Is there a case where jaydebeapi has this similar problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Raspberry pi No module named 'cx\_Oracle'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54824962/raspberry-pi-no-module-named-cx-oracle). It doesn't seem Java should be needed for accessing Oracle DB with Python from a Raspberry Pi.

Comment: @aled I have to use ARM32 but oracle has no module for arm32. so I can use only jaydebeapi.